# Troubleshoot Cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have this AWS exercise scenario, where your customer has not used AWS before, and is encountering issues when trying to launch a web application as a proof of concept.
So far your customer has launched an AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) and an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance acting as the web server. Both are deployed in a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) on AWS. While your customer's initial deployment aims to present a static web page to its users (demo.html located in the document root of the web server

Below is the cloud formation script:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: |

  AWS CloudFormation SA Assignment - WARNING: You will be billed for the
  AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template and consume all your
  promotional credit. 

  We recommend you create a billing alert. Once you submit your
  answers delete the CloudFormation stack and terminate any other resources launched
  in relation to this exercise. 

  Feel free to do that as soon as you have submitted
  your document and before your interview.

Parameters:


  CandidateName:
    Description: 'Please input your first and last name:'
    Type: String
    MaxLength: '50'
    MinLength: '3'
    ConstraintDescription: Please input your full name.

Resources:


    SAVPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        InstanceTenancy: default
        EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
        EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [SAVPC, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PublicSubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicSubnetA, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PublicSubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1b
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'True'
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicSubnetB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PrivateSubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateSubnetA, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    PrivateSubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
        AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1b
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateSubnetB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SAIGW:
      Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
      Properties:
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [IGW, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SANetworkACL:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [NACL, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SARoutePublic:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PublicRoute, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SARoutePrivate:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [PrivateRoute, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SAInstance1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
      Properties:
        DisableApiTermination: 'false'
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: stop
        ImageId: ami-047bb4163c506cd98
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        Monitoring: 'false'
        UserData: 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
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [Instance1, !Ref 'CandidateName']]
        NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'
          GroupSet: [!Ref 'SASGapp']

    SAelb:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
      Properties:
        Subnets: [!Ref 'PublicSubnetB']
        Instances: [!Ref 'SAInstance1']
        SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'SASGELB']
        Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
        HealthCheck:
          HealthyThreshold: '2'
          Interval: '15'
          Target: TCP:443
          Timeout: '5'
          UnhealthyThreshold: '2'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: !Join ['-', [ELB, !Ref 'CandidateName']]

    SASGELB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: SA Assignment - ELB security group
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: ELBSecurityGroup

    SASGapp:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: SA Assignment - App server security group
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        Tags:
          - Key: environment
            Value: sa-assignment
          - Key: Name
            Value: AppServerSecurityGroup

    SANACLEntry1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        Egress: 'true'
        Protocol: '-1'
        RuleAction: allow
        RuleNumber: '100'
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'

    SANACLEntry2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        Protocol: '-1'
        RuleAction: allow
        RuleNumber: '100'
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'

    subnetacl1:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'

    subnetacl2:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetB'

    subnetacl3:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetA'

    subnetacl4:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
      Properties:
        NetworkAclId: !Ref 'SANetworkACL'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetB'

    SAIGWAttachment:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref 'SAVPC'
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'SAIGW'

    subnetRoutePublicA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetA'

    subnetRoutePublicB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PublicSubnetB'

    subnetRoutePrivateA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePrivate'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetA'

    subnetRoutePrivateB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePrivate'
        SubnetId: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetB'

    publicroute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        RouteTableId: !Ref 'SARoutePublic'
        GatewayId: !Ref 'SAIGW'
      DependsOn: SAIGW


Outputs:


  LoadBalancerDNSName:
    Description: The DNSName of the load balancer
    Value: !GetAtt SAelb.DNSName
```

what is the problem with this, is ELB configuration all correct?.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the template. It deploys.

Comment: Is this an assignment you are meant to complete to prove your competency in AWS before applying for a job as a Solutions Architect somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have run your template with [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) and got the following warnings:

```
E3012 Property Resources/SAVPC/Properties/EnableDnsSupport should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:33:9

E3012 Property Resources/SAVPC/Properties/EnableDnsHostnames should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:34:9

W3010 Don't hardcode eu-west-1a for AvailabilityZones
logesh.template:45:9

E3012 Property Resources/PublicSubnetA/Properties/MapPublicIpOnLaunch should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:46:9

W3010 Don't hardcode eu-west-1b for AvailabilityZones
logesh.template:58:9

E3012 Property Resources/PublicSubnetB/Properties/MapPublicIpOnLaunch should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:59:9

W3010 Don't hardcode eu-west-1a for AvailabilityZones
logesh.template:71:9

W3010 Don't hardcode eu-west-1b for AvailabilityZones
logesh.template:83:9

E3012 Property Resources/SAInstance1/Properties/DisableApiTermination should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:133:9

E3012 Property Resources/SAInstance1/Properties/Monitoring should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:137:9

E3012 Property Resources/SAInstance1/Properties/NetworkInterfaces/0/AssociatePublicIpAddress should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:145:11

E3012 Property Resources/SAInstance1/Properties/NetworkInterfaces/0/DeleteOnTermination should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:146:11

E3012 Property Resources/SAInstance1/Properties/NetworkInterfaces/0/DeviceIndex should be of type String
logesh.template:148:11

E3012 Property Resources/SANACLEntry1/Properties/Egress should be of type Boolean
logesh.template:200:9

E3012 Property Resources/SANACLEntry1/Properties/Protocol should be of type Integer
logesh.template:201:9

E3012 Property Resources/SANACLEntry1/Properties/RuleNumber should be of type Integer
logesh.template:203:9

E3012 Property Resources/SANACLEntry2/Properties/Protocol should be of type Integer
logesh.template:210:9

E3012 Property Resources/SANACLEntry2/Properties/RuleNumber should be of type Integer
logesh.template:212:9

W3005 Obsolete DependsOn on resource (SAIGW), dependency already enforced by a "Ref" at Resources/publicroute/Properties/GatewayId/Ref
logesh.template:275:7
```

You might want to correct these problems before proceeding.

Comment: The script run and creates all the resources as needed. Need to troubleshoot why im not able to access the demo.html page

Comment: @logesh My guess would be that your security groups do not have ingress rules for accessing port 80 from the internet.

Comment: that is one of the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. ELB is not configured to receive public internet traffic.
2. ELB is not configured for the right availability zone where the EC2 instance is running
3. ELB health check is not configured to access HTTP 80 to EC2
4. EC2 is not configured to receive traffic from the ELB